# GCP SSL firewall rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

RESOLVED: See comments

I am trying to enable SSL from outside the GCP network and have temporarily edited the HTTPS rule to allow all networks and I have applied it to all instances in the network.

However, when I try to telnet (to a Linux VM) from my laptop on 443 it still fails (I can do it on port 22) and on port testing web pages it says the port is closed. what am I missing to implement the rule correctly?

- default-allow-https   ingress 1000    0.0.0.0/0   allow   tcp:443
- default-allow-ssh ingress 65534   0.0.0.0/0   allow   tcp:22

I've also got the default http, icmp, internal and rdp rules.

Comment: Do you have a service on the VM(s) listening on port 443? The VMs are running the SSH daemon (`sshd`) and so they'll respond to connection requests on the default SSH port (22). But, you'll need to have a service listening on 443 if you want to connect to a service on that port.

Comment: Port 443 is typically used by a webserver or HTTP-based application. What did you install and how did you configure SSL/TLS in that application? Suggestion, telnet does not understand HTTP, use a tool that does, such as `curl`.

Comment: this resolved.... turned out firewall was fine. my issue was around the service i was interacting with and a geographical restriction.